# Anki decks for understanding spoken Norwegian

Tags: electronic-resources, anki, norwegian

Among the Anki decks that teach Norwegian there are at least three with substantial amount of sound files; they and others can be found at https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/norwegian. (There might be more such decks elsewhere, for all I know.)

Which Anki deck is (or which are) the best for learning to **understand spoken** Norwegian, and what are their pros and cons?